# NMSSH file not found

Tags: swift, nmssh

My goal is to create ssh connection between my iPhone and my raspberry pi. I installed this framework by using pods. That was successful, but here comes the problem. 

https://github.com/NMSSH/NMSSH

This page writes the following:
Add #import NMSSH/NMSSH.h> to your source file.

But what is my souce file? Where should I place this import?

I can insert it into a swift file and when I placed it into an an objective-c file, I got NMSSH/NMSSH.h file not found.

What is the solution?

Thanks

Comment: If you are working inside a Swift project, you need to put that import statement into an [objective-c bridging header](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) file.

Comment: Thanks, that threw no error. And if that is done, where should I write my code that uses nmssh. I mean, should I import something in ViewController.swift? Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't have to. Just write your code :)

Comment: NMSSHSession *session = [NMSSHSession connectToHost:@"127.0.0.1:22"
                                       withUsername:@"user"]; I pasted this line in ViewController.swift into the viewDidLoad function but I got Expected expression in container loteral, consecutive statements on a line must be seperated by ;, expected , separator. Do you think this should run without error or should just this code be upgraded? Thanks

Comment: That's objective-c code, though, no Swift. It should probs look sth. like this: `let session: NMSSHSession = NMSSHSession.connectToHost(url: "", username: "")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working inside a Swift project, you need to put that import statement into an objective-c bridging header file.
Check out [Apple's documentation on bridging headers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/importing_objective-c_into_swift).

Also, you need to write the equivalent Swift code, instead of the code examples on the Github page.

Comment: My very last question: How can I know the expressions in swift for this library. For example:     [session authenticateByPassword:@"pass"]; What is this in swift? Or am I supposed to code in objective-c when using this library? Thanks

Comment: No problem. Probably: `session.authenticate(password: "")`. But that really depends on what they chose to name it.

Comment: Is it well-documented anywhere or  you just know it from experience? Thx

Comment: Nope, sorry. I have tried the library a few weeks ago but then changed my approach so I didn't bother using it / researching on it anymore.

Comment: What did you change it to?

Comment: Oh I figured I didn't actually have to connect to my server to read the database (which sounds really dumb to anyone w/ server / database experience), ha. That probably doesn't help you, though.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you, but I get "NMSSH/NMSSH.h not found again". The other error is failed to emit precompiled header and it continues with the path of the bridging header file. I created another project and installed pods again but I have those two errors again. Do you have any idea how to solve it? Thanks

Comment: So the new error is in the new project? Have you setup the bridging header from inside the project or just copied the file in? Check the build settings (search for bridging header) for the header’s path. It needs to be correct.